# Delay before JobScheduler executes job first time?

Tags: android

I'm noticing that when I schedule a job to run with JobScheduler there always appears to be at least a 10+ minute delay before it start the job the first time.  Does anybody know why?  I started digging through the code today, but I didn't find the reason.  I'm still looking, but I figured I would ask.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Log.d("XXX", "Scheduling MyJobService to run.");
            ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
            JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(MyJobService.JOB_ID, serviceName)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30), JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                    .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
                    .build();
            JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            scheduler.cancel(MyJobService.JOB_ID);
            scheduler.schedule(job);
        }
    }

    public class MyJobService extends JobService {

        public final static int JOB_ID = 1000;

        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
            Log.d("XXX", "Job started");
            jobFinished(params, true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of me restarting my test app twice.

```
06-14 16:53:00.335 29024-29024/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Scheduling MyJobService to run.
06-14 17:03:17.173 29024-29024/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
06-14 17:12:05.158 31668-31668/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Scheduling MyJobService to run.
06-14 17:22:07.280 31668-31668/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
```

I'm running Android N preview release 4 on a Nexus 6.

Comment: Did you get a perfect solution for this? Even I am facing same issue

Comment: I believe it is due to the doze optimizations, so no solution is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is something that was added in Android N.  When they release the code I'm sure I'll be able to see what is causing the delay.  Most likely it is due to "Doze" optimizations.

I tested on a Nexus 6p and a Moto X Pure, both running Marshmallow.  Both devices ran the job almost instantly.

From the Nexus 6P

```
06-16 14:55:03.045 13459-13459/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Scheduling MyJobService to run.
06-16 14:55:08.069 13459-13459/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
```

From the Moto X Pure

```
06-16 14:55:03.045 13459-13459/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Scheduling MyJobService to run.
06-16 14:55:08.069 13459-13459/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
06-16 14:52:19.315 19812-19812/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Scheduling MyJobService to run.
06-16 14:52:24.342 19812-19812/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
06-16 14:52:56.480 19812-19812/com.example.jobschedulertest.jobschedulertest D/XXX: Job started
```